# Spring MVC URL Redirecting to login page

Tags: spring-mvc

I have requirement is like below.

The user can call the url like domainname/applicationname/instancesname
For Ex: abc.com/xyz/pqr

From the URL with instance name I need to take and i need to redirect to the login page.

but what ever the user is enter the URL, I should keep in browser url.
[Because user may bookmark the URL]

Think I will receive the instance name dynamically.

how can i use this in Spring MVC.

The main concept is single url we are handling with multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don not pass any url parameters with abc.com/xyz/pq this url it wont be a problem. Book mark url will work since you have the request mapping in your controller.